# How to stop bounce rate manipulation

Tags: seo, google-analytics, spam

Using  Google analytics I have started noticing some sort of spam/attack/bounce rate manipulation happening with one of my sites. Essentially, there are a large number of daily hits from the same user, searching for the same long tail keyword, that always immediately bounces out of the page. This has been going on for over a month. My question is this: is there any way to track this user/ip and block them from the site, or any other technique that I could use to keep this from affecting my bounce rate and messing with my analytics data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try blocking the IP with .htaccess http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess5.shtml

Comment: How do I track down that specific IP address? GA doesn't seem to make that too easy.

Comment: You need to look at the server logs (IIS/Apache logs to see who is making the call with the long-tail keyword and use the IP info to block them). Hopefully, you have access logs recording the IP info as well.

Answer (score 5):

Given that you tagged your question with *Google Analytics*, i assume that your question is directed to identifying this false traffic so you can prevent it from contaminating your web metrics--rather than how to actually stop the offending activity. In any event, my question is only directed to the former.

Rather than having to refer to your server activity logs, or adding a node to your production data flow, you can do this solely from within Google Analytics.

From the *Analytics Settings* Panel, click *Filter Manager*, then enter a name for this filter in the text box.

The filter *field* will be *Hostname*, and once you click this you'll see a textbox in which you enter a pattern for the hostname. so you would enter something like this:

^somedomain.com$

The benefits of this approach is that it will work based on information already made available to you in GA--the Hostname, which is an attribute of every pageview from the suspicious source.